# Query's for a mock Facebook SQL DB for likes and location

Tags: sql, database

I've created a mock SQL database for a theoretical "facebook" SQL db below. How do I:

1) find all the `page_urls` (from the table `fb_pages`) that were 'liked' by users from Isreal?

and

2) find all `pageURL`s that were 'liked' by users that uploaded at least 2 photos within the past year?

I can edit the tables themselves (add/remove new columns, etc) if need be. Any ideas?

---

### **tables**

Table 1: 
`FB_profile` (`userID`, `profile_URL`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Gender`, `Current_Location`, `Birthdate`, `AboutMe`)

Table2: `Location` (`userID`, `city`, `country`, `state`, `zipcode`)

Table 3: `FB_pages` (`pageID`, `pageURL`, `pageName`, `likedBy_userID`)

Table 4: `photo` (`userID`, `URL`, `image`, `photoID`, `created_timestamp`, `caption`, `albumID`)

Table 5: `FriendRelation` (`userID_1`, `userID_2`, `AreFriends`)

Table 6: `user_status` (`userID`, `statusID`, `status`, `URL`, `timestamp`)

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) find all the page_urls (from the table fb_pages) that were 'liked' by users from Israel?

Just join `fb_pages` with `fb_profile` on users that come from Israel.

```
select distinct pa.page_url
from fb_pages pa
inner join fb_profile pr 
    on  pr.userID = pa.likedBy_userID
    and pr.Current_Location = 'Israel'
```

2) find all pageURLs that were 'liked' by users that uploaded at least 2 photos within the past year?

You can use an aggregate subquery to pull out users that uploaed more than 2 photos over the last year, and then join the results with `fb_pages`.

```
select distinct pa.page_url
from fb_pages pa
inner join (
    select userID
    from photo
    where created_timestamp >= now() - interval 1 year  -- or whatever syntax works for your RDBMS
    having count(*) >= 2
) ph on ph.userID = pa.likedBy_userID
```

---

Note on the design: the use of `select distinct` in both queries indicates that you should have a separate, referential table to store the pages, and another table to store the visits (as of now, you are storing the visits in the table called `fb_pages`, and there is no referential table that list all available pages).

Comment: Thanks! One last question, sorry, I need to now write a query that returns the number of male friends living in israel, and all the female friends for a given user: (1. Query that returns two rows -- one for each number, and, 2. Query that returns 1 row with 2 columns)

Comment: @em4019: 2 questions were already too many for a SO post... If you have more, then you would need to ask a new question.